# Need help finding this manga

Tags: story-identification, manga

So I read this manga on manga rock but it isn’t there anymore.

It’s basically about a guy who I think works in this organization where if you get arrested or are a criminal you are given the choice of working in this virtual reality simulator or die I think. The main guy chooses to work in the simulator, which is a chair that has something like a headset that connects to the chair, which then takes your mind to this world where you are tested to fight different things with changes in difficulty the more you rank up. The only problem is that, depending I think on how high your IQ is, that is how many points or how strong you are and what weapons you can create or make. The main guy meets some other guy who ends up being like a psychopath who is really good at killing and is only a few points lowers than the main guy.

Towards the middle they end up creating a group of people including some of the staff to work together to defeat the big boss in the virtual world. A blonde guy who was a big coward in the beginning if I remember correctly, sacrifices himself for his team, and a few others die as well. Him and the psychopath end up being a great team and they end up winning in the end.

A little extra facts: I think the main guy uses a sword or a katana as his main weapon. The picture that I remember as the cover was him getting a mugshot and holding up a sign which had the name of the manga.

I don’t remember any more, I hope someone can tell me the name, I really liked this manga.

Comment: Could it be [Carpe Diem](http://mangarock.com/manga/mrs-serie-40305)?

Comment: No it’s not that one